# Using GAE SDK for both Python and Go

Tags: google-app-engine

I have used the GAE SDK for developing Python apps for a year or so.  I would like to try my hand with Go.  There is a different SDK download for Go and the docs say it is slightly different than the Python SDK.  My question is do I need to install this separately and use different SDKs for Python/Go?  Or is the Go SDK "inclusive" of the Python SDK?

Comment: Interesting question, I'm a go developer and I noticed go depends heavily on python (well at least the SDK does, not sure how it works on google). Anyway you may just try and find out as you know both language!

Comment: I've just tried installing a PHP SDK alongside Python, and it won't install.